# What speed does maps.app use when calculating walking times

Tags: ios, maps

I like walking to places. Before I leave I see how long it will take me to walk there in the maps.app. Often, I find I get there 15% faster than the time displayed on my iPhone. But again I am quite young and walk faster than usual.

Humans walk around 1.4 metres/second. What speed does the maps.app use to calculate walking travel times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Map is set to miles, but you could do the same for kilometres..

Drop a pin & keep moving it until it says it will take an hour to walk there.
Check the distance.
Mine says 2.8 miles.

Google tells me 2.8 mph is approx 1.25 m/s